# Verify if connection to the mySQL exists or let Apache do it

Tags: php, mysql

I created a function to connect to the db in php:

```
function fn_connect($is_write = false)
{
    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db = 'name_db';

    if ($is_write) {
        $user = 'user_write';
        $pwd = 'password_write';
    } else {
        $user = 'user_read';
        $pwd = 'password_read';
    }

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die('The database is not available. Please, try again later.');
    }

    return $conn;
}
```

When I need to connect, im calling it (and closing it) like this

```
$conn = fn_connect(true);

$stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute();
....
$stmt->close();

$conn->close();
```

I thought it will be a good idea to verify if the connection exists, that way, I guess, I save connecting to the db every time for nothing, like this:

```
if (!isset($conn)) $conn = fn_connect(true);

$stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute();
....
$stmt->close();

if (isset($conn)) $conn->close();
```

Is this a good idea, a good practice? Should I jut connect normally and let Apache/PHP do the rest (no need to verify nothing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practiose and good style to check the connection, before letting php try to get or send data.

What is not good style is to use die in your connection, because it leaves a broken page.

Better is to design the page so that page still works when the connection is broken.